# Как скомпилировать OpenGL(freeglut) с MinGW на С++

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw

Проекты на С собираю вот так:

```
gcc -c -o example.o example.c -I"C:\mycpp\include"
gcc -o example.exe example.o -L"C:\mycpp\lib" -lfreeglut -lopengl32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows
```

Вопрос: Как собрать проект не на `С` а на `С++` если просто поменять `gcc` на `g++` или поменять флаги то или вообще не компилируется или вываливается куча ошибок.

Вопрос: Как скомпилировать именно С++ код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Наверное, вначале стоит заменить расширение файла с .c на .cpp (или любое другое, которое g++ воспримет за "свое"), иначе придется еще уговаривать его доп. опциями "скушать" этот файл.
2. В С++ (в отличие от С), используется декорирование имен функций, поэтому каждую функцию из библиотеки для С надо объявлять со словами extern "C" (в начале). Но думаю, что это в заголовочном файле глюта уже сделано за Вас.
3. Пример из глюта на С++ (он использует STL) с динамической линковкой я собирал так (откуда взял список библиотек - уже точно не помню. Скорее, вычитал в документации):

   g++ sample-1.cpp -o sapmle-1 -lfreeglut -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows

Comment: Пришлось немного доработать вашу команду добавив в нее пути к подключаемым файлам и библиотекам получилась следующая команда: `g++ example.cpp -o example -I"C:\mycpp\include" -L"C:\mycpp\lib" -lfreeglut -lopengl32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows -lfreeglut -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows`  теперь все компилируется, спасибо.

Comment: Вот еще вариант как на `C` компилировать только одной командой: `gcc c2.c -o c2.exe -I"C:\mycpp\include" -L"C:\mycpp\lib" -lfreeglut -lopengl32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows`

Comment: И соответственно на `С++`: `g++ c2.cpp -o c2.exe -I"C:\mycpp\include" -L"C:\mycpp\lib" -lfreeglut -lopengl32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows`

Comment: Оставлю этот тут может кому то пригодится для GLFW: `g++ 2.cpp -o 2 -I"C:\mycpp\glfw-3.2.1\glfw-3.2.1\include\GLFW" -I"C:\mycpp\glm-0.9.8.5\glm\glm" -L"C:\mycpp\glfw-3.2.1.bin.WIN32\glfw-3.2.1.bin.WIN32\lib-mingw" -Wl,--subsystem,windows -lglfw3 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows
`